# How to mount an Oracle database to new instance?

Tags: windows-server-2003, database, oracle

I have an instance of Oracle 10g R2 installed on Windows Server 2003. This instance was running a database which does not have any backup. Now the OS went down, could not be repaired, and all I got is the running files of the old instance.

How can I restore the database from these files to new instance?

A step-by-step guide will be much appreciated because I'm new with Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you will have to do the following:

1. Install Oracle (same version if possible or newer) on a new server.
2. Create the Windows services using [oradim.exe](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/create003.htm#ADMIN12481) (uses the sames SID than before)
3. Copy all the files from the old instance on the new server to the exact same locations (or recreate control files using *"CREATE CONTROLFILE"* and specify new locations)
4. Cross your fingers and start the new instance.
5. Backup your database and schedule recurring backups.

Some changes may occurs according to the configuration of the old instance (use of the archive log mode, ...)

Comment: Note on step 3: Preferably, copy all database files to the same locations. If you cannot, you'll have to use the CREATE CONTROLFILE command to let the instance know where your files are.

Comment: @DCookie thanks for your input, I edit my answer according to your comment.

Comment: No problem. I did edit to clarify that you need to put the files in the same locations or else you *must* recreate the control file.

Answer (score 1):

It depends...

Do you have the online redo logs from the time of the OS crash? Was the database running in ARCHIVELOG mode, and if so, do you have the archived redo logs?

Comment: I don't think you need any archived log files in this situation, where the OS went belly up on a running instance. All you need are the database files including, as you rightly ask, the online redo logs. Hopefully the OS crash didn't corrupt any of the database files.

Comment: And, as the OP states, there is no backup, and therefore archived log files will be of no value.